# Keepalived's virtual_router_id - should it be unique per node?

Tags: high-availability, keepalived

I have two nodes running keepalived, and two VIP, e.g.

```
Node 1      Node 2
VIP1        VIP2
```

So in each node, I have two definition of `vrrp_instance`, so I assume the two `vrrp_instance` in my `keepalived.conf` suppose to be unique, but they can be the same values on another node, right?

Comment: If they're the same instance, they should have the same instance ID. If they're different instances, they should have different instance IDs. An instance that only existed on one node wouldn't be very useful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Different VRRP instances should have different `virtual_router_id` values. Same VRRP instances should have the same value.

You can read the following from `man keepalived.conf`:

```
# arbitary unique number 0..255
# used to differentiate multiple instances of vrrpd
# running on the same NIC (and hence same socket).
virtual_router_id 51
```

To summarize, you need to have the same value on the members of same cluster. If you have another cluster, its members should have another value. The `virtual_router_id` should be unique per VRRP cluster.

Comment: Hi, in my network I have any set of keepalived nodes which has the dupltcated virtual_router_id, but I have tested the function is ok, execept there are warning log syslog, does it matter? Also, is it recommended to use the same string for both vrrp_instance and virtual_router_id?  Thanks